# unable to write the complete audiostream to an audio file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to convert audio to audiostream and then back to audio using java. When i read the wav file into the byte array it shows around 30000 bytes but when i write it onto a new fle, it just writes 44 bytes.Please tell me where am i going wrong. The code snippet is as follows:

```
    File src = new File("C:\\test.wav");
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(src);  
    byte[] data = new byte[ais.available()];
    int x = ais.read(data);

    int n = AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File("C:\\test2.wav"));
    System.out.println("x="+x+"  n="+n);
```

The output of n is 44.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you have read the entire contents of the AudioInputStream into the byte array. This means when you pass the AudioInputStream instance to the AudioSystem.write() method it will already be at the end of the file. (The 44 bytes it is writing are probably just header information or something similar.)

The quick way to diagnose is to comment out the call to ais.read(data) and see if it starts writing out the file properly.

A possible solution is to use the mark() and reset() methods on the AudioInputStream to move back to the start of the file after reading the file into the byte array.